# Oddo dependency psycopg2 can't be installed on Mac

Tags: python, odoo

I successfully cloned Odoo v15.0 repo, and I'm trying to install python dependencies using `pip install -r requirements.txt`, but I got the following error:

```
Collecting psycopg2==2.8.6
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /private/var/folders/k6/zsl2d2vn7jl7mmg04j067dp00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-mw1wzrzi/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing /private/var/folders/k6/zsl2d2vn7jl7mmg04j067dp00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-mw1wzrzi/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/k6/zsl2d2vn7jl7mmg04j067dp00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-mw1wzrzi/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/k6/zsl2d2vn7jl7mmg04j067dp00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-mw1wzrzi/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/k6/zsl2d2vn7jl7mmg04j067dp00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-mw1wzrzi/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

From what I understand from the error message, I should replace library `psycopg2` for `psycopg2_binary`, but I don't think that's what Odoo expects.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Odoo depends on [psycopg2](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/requirements.txt#L26-L27), it does not matter if you use the binaries or build it yourself

Comment: You need to have PostgreSQL headers installed to compile C modules that use them.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a package manager that can take care of this for you -- the one I personally use is Nix, which will also make pip unnecessary; but if you're already comfortable with macports or Homebrew, they probably also have what you need to install the dependencies required for a successful pip invocation.